# discord.py bot create an input embed

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my discord.py bot create an embed after the input of a member. For example {!embed Hello there beauty} and the title is hello there, the description is beauty, just a bit more usefull :D. Like multiple words on each variable, separated by a comma

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class drops(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role(795263101309681690, 795263101309681688, 779491292627468308)
    async def embed(self, ctx, *,dropalert, start, social, location, write): #don't mind the dropalert, take it as a title
        dropEmbed = discord.Embed(title = dropalert, colour = 0xFF0000)
        dropEmbed.add_field(name='Drop starts:', value = start)
        dropEmbed.add_field(name="Social club:", value = social)
        dropEmbed.add_field(name = "Location:", value = location)
        dropEmbed.set_footer(text = write)

        await ctx.send(embed=dropEmbed)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(drops(bot))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `!embed "Hello there" beauty` and remove the `, *,` in there cmd args

Comment: No problem :) ;)